# How to add a count/sum and group by in a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just a question on displaying a row on flight level and displaying a count on how many crew members on that flight.

I want to change the output so it will only display a single record at flight level and it will display two additional columns. One column (cabincrew) is the count of crew members that have the `'CREWTYPE' = 'F'` and the other column (cockpitcrew) is the count of crew members that have the `'CREWTYPE' = 'C'.

So the query result should look like:

```
Flight  DepartureDate DepartureAirport  CREWBASE  CockpitCrew CabinCrew
LS361    2016-05-19     BFS                BFS        0            3
```

Can I have a little help tweaking the below query please:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT cd.*, c.*, l.Carrier, l.FlightNumber, l.Suffix, l.ScheduledDepartureDate, l.ScheduledDepartureAirport
FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LegKey ORDER BY UpdateID DESC) AS RowNumber FROM Data.Crew) c
INNER JOIN 
Data.CrewDetail cd
ON c.UpdateID = cd.CrewUpdateID
AND cd.IsPassive = 0
AND RowNumber = 1
INNER JOIN 
Data.Leg l
ON c.LegKey = l.LegKey
)
SELECT
    sac.Airline + CAST(sac.FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + sac.Suffix AS Flight
,   sac.DepartureDate
,   sac.DepartureAirport
,   sac.CREWBASE
,   sac.CREWTYPE
,   sac.EMPNO
,   sac.FIRSTNAME
,   sac.LASTNAME
,   sac.SEX
FROM 
Staging.SabreAssignedCrew sac
LEFT JOIN CTE cte
ON sac.Airline + CAST(sac.FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + sac.Suffix = cte.Carrier + CAST(cte.FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + cte.Suffix
AND sac.DepartureDate = cte.ScheduledDepartureDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PLEASE TRY THIS.

```
  SELECT    Flight,
            DepartureDate,
            DepartureAirport,  
            CREWBASE,
            SUM(CASE WHEN CREWTYPE = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CabinCrew ,
            SUM(CASE WHEN CREWTYPE = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CockpitCrew
      FROM  @Table
    GROUP BY Flight, DepartureDate, DepartureAirport, CREWBASE
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This:

```
select Flight, DepartureDate, DepartureAirport,CREWBASE,
count(case when CREWTYPE='F' then 1 end ) as CabinCrew,count(case when CREWTYPE='C' then 1 end ) as CockpitCrew 
from Staging.SabreAssignedCrew
group by Flight, DepartureDate, DepartureAirport,CREWBASE
```